# Process.pause/suspend (equivalent of SIGTSTP) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, process, signals

What I trying to figure out is the following - if I trap SIGTSTP (resulting e.g. from Ctrl-Z) in my Ruby program, then run some code, how in the end can I achieve (from Ruby) the same effect as if I didn't trap SIGTSTP? That is, how can I suspend the process so that it could be later continued via SIGCONT?